# How can I make cleartype change subpixel layout when I rotate my tablet?

Tags: windows-8, cleartype, display-rotation

I have a tablet running a full version of windows 8.

I have cleartype enabled, but when I flip the device, the cleartype does not take seem to take into account the change in subpixel layout. Is there a tool that can detect this orientation change and reconfigure cleartype?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of the cleartyped text in portrait and landscape mode?

Comment: @gronostaj: Not easily, but I can verify with the magnifier that the rendering is identical in all four orientations. I'd expect the red and blue fringes to swap sides upon a 180 degree rotation - they do not.

Comment: this is by design. ClearType has issues with rotating the screen, that why MS doesn't use it for their "modern" UI: http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120303/cleartype-takes-a-back-seat-for-windows-8-metro/